# Suds Message is missing Element. Soapui creates the correct message from the WSDL

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, suds, ignition

I have seen related questions to this in posts that are 6 or 7 years old, but have not found a good answer. The DELV_NUM element is in the WSDL, but I believe it is marked as optional and mybe the reason suds ignores it. 
I did not make the WSDL file and cannot make changes to it. If I can modify the suds message to appear like the Soapui message, the response should work fine. I am limited to patching and modifying suds, as it is part of Inductive Automation's Ignition platform.

**This is the message request sent from suds**

[image]

**This is the message request from Soapui using the same WSDL**

[image]

I can share the WSDL if that would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the  element to the request, you can use the client.factory.create() method.

Solution could work like this:

```
# Create a Processing_Req object
processing_req = client.factory.create('{http://wackerneuson.com/wn/in/Conveyor_Belt/ConveyorBeltProcessing}Processing_Req')

# Create a Record object which is a child of Processing_Req
record = client.factory.create('{http://wackerneuson.com/wn/if/Conveyor_Belt/ConveyorBeltProcessing}Processing_Req.record')

# set the DELV_NUM element which is a child of the record element.
record.DELV_NUM = '82934258'

# append the new record object to the processing_req object
processing_req.record.append(record)

# make the request with the new record object created and populated
request = client.service.Processing_OS(record)
```